# How to load csv with variables in one column into dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv with just one column:

```
demand;;;
1;4;3;2
2;3;4;2
3;3;3;4
4;4;3;2
workhours;;;
1;160;;
2;80;;
3;40;;
4;80;;
```

How can i load it into python such that the first dataframe will be:

```
 index    column1 column2 column3
 1          1       4        3     
 2          2       3        4    
 3          3       3        3    
 4          4       4        3
```

And the second will be

```
 index    column1 column2 column3
 1          160     0        0    
 2          80      0        0   
 3          40      0        0  
 4          80      0        0
```

Comment: Can You share that .csv for download?

Comment: @PiotrŻak mine is much bigger, but to create this simplified version, it is enough to copy the first part, paste it into excel and save as .csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On approach is to read in the whole csv, and create groups based on where there are NaN in all 3 columns. Then create a dictionary based on those groups:

```py
from io import StringIO
from pprint import pprint

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''demand;;;
1;4;3;2
2;3;4;2
3;3;3;4
4;4;3;2
workhours;;;
1;160;;
2;80;;
3;40;;
4;80;;
'''), sep=';', index_col=0, names=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])

# Create Groups where all row values are NaN
groups = tuple(df.groupby((~df.index.str.isnumeric()).cumsum()))
dfs = {}
for i, (_, sub_df) in enumerate(groups):
    # Get Name From Index as Key and set value as rest of the Frame
    dfs[sub_df.index[0]] = sub_df.iloc[1:]

pprint(dfs)
```

`dfs`:

```
{'demand':    column1  column2  column3
1      4.0      3.0      2.0
2      3.0      4.0      2.0
3      3.0      3.0      4.0
4      4.0      3.0      2.0,
 'workhours':    column1  column2  column3
1    160.0      NaN      NaN
2     80.0      NaN      NaN
3     40.0      NaN      NaN
4     80.0      NaN      NaN}
```

---

Some groupby options:

1. Assuming that there are no rows with all NaNs except the row which where table breaks occur:

```
groups = tuple(df.groupby(df.isna().all(axis=1).cumsum()))
```

2. Assuming that all indexes except the row where breaks occur are numeric:

```
groups = tuple(df.groupby((~df.index.str.isnumeric()).cumsum()))
```

3. Assuming there are both occasionally non-numeric indexes and rows with NaNs, but that only rows where both occur are breaks:

```
groups = tuple(df.groupby((~df.index.str.isnumeric() & df.isna().all(axis=1)).cumsum()))
```

Comment: Nice solution, but issues will happen in the case where there are 3 NAs in the different columns that are not related to a change of data content.

Comment: A check that the index is non-numeric as well could be added to be double sure.

Comment: This is my preferred approach. Using `not isnumeric()` is a good way to get the labels out, without worrying about valid `NA` values for certain rows. Btw, in your code, you're not using the `i` from `enumerate` so may as just do `for _, sub_df in groups:`

Answer (score 2):

Given the shape of the data (index column containing name of the data -demand, workhours- then indexes) you gave you can try:

```
df = pd.read_csv("yourcsv.csv", 
                sep=";", 
                names=["column1","column2","column3"]).fillna(0)
```

And then create a new column `label` having the name of the data for the whole corresponding chunk:

```
df["label"] = df["index"].apply(lambda x: x if not x.isnumeric() else pd.NA).fillna(method = "ffill")
df = df[df["index"] != df["label"]]
```

This will give you a dataframe looking like this

[image]

You can then separate the data based on the "label" column:

```
df_demand = df.loc[df.label=="demand"].set_index('index').drop(['label'], axis=1)
df_workhours = df.loc[df.label=="workhours"].set_index('index').drop(['label'], axis=1)
```

[image: df_workhours]

[image: df_demand]

Comment: Thx, but the essence was to divide it somehow into multple dataframes. I can do it with df[:28] for example, but i have lots of those divisions where each division is when index is a string.

Comment: Sorry, read the question too quickly. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: To create the multiple dataframes, instead of doing an explicit check for certain labels, you could use `itertools.groupby` or `df['label'].unique()` to get each group of rows associated with that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
pd.read_csv('filename.csv', index_col = 0, sep = ';')
```

where 0 in index_col = 0 is the position of the column you want to use as an index